# Insert spaces between words that have meaning in R

Tags: r, nlp

I want to put spaces between words that have meaning in R.

For example I want to change this sentence :

```
sentence<-c("haveagoodday!")
```

to this one :

```
"have a good day !"
```

is it possible ?

Comment: That's likely to be very difficult, because there are cases (e.g. "doghouse" vs. "dog house") where the result is ambiguous.  I imagine there are others where "abcd" has words "ab" and "abc" at the start, but only "cd" is also a word, not "d", so your code can't just pick the longest match, it may need to back off.

Comment: I second @user2554330's comment, this is going to be very difficult to do, and even harder to do well and consistently. If the lack of spaces in `sentence` is native, then go to whomever creates that data source and ask them to be clearer. If the lack of spaces is due to something you've done (tried to parse a file, scrape a website), then I recommend you fix the parsing/extraction/scraping portion so that spaces are preserved. Either way, it's much easier to fix whatever formed `sentence` than it will be to find the best places for spaces.